# Membership state deceased

Tags: civimember

Can anyone please explain why a membership state Deceased exists (along with the contact's state)? Is there a use case where the membership is Deceased, but the contact is not?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have thought that just a membership would be deceased. As for logic, I've always made the assumptions that it's a safeguard from 'accidentally' soliciting membership renewals.